# Just loading php in Obj-C(Iphone/Xcode)

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode, load

I have an app that when you press a button, it loads a php page. I don't need to get any strings from it. I just need to request the page without it being seen by the user when the button is pressed. I don't want to use a uiwebview as they use up too much resources.

How can I load a php page without showing it to the user on the press of a button?
(Preferable code that can be inserted into an IBAction).

Ps. I've googled for 1/2 hour or so an I couldn't find anything some I'm asking here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need any data from the web page, you just need to load it once to notify the web server that the user has done something? You can simply use:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://blaablaa.com/hello.php";
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

If you need to get the result for your request (did it succeed/fail), implement

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // your stuff here
}
```

in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/file.php"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```